# How to limit characters using CSS pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I'm using JS and CSS pseudo elements to apply a class to the first line of a div and then to only display that first line and hide the other content inside that div.

I'm using this to limit the amount of content displayed inside a div on the index page of a tumblr theme as each post is limited to a square box which I don't want to exceed in height.

Ideally I'd like to choose the correct amount of characters to display as opposed to just the first line. I wondered if anyone could suggest a way of doing this? Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="text-p-pad text-body">
    {Body}
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text-body p :not(.index-hide)  {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$( ".text-body p::first-line" ).addClass( $( "index-hide" ) );
```

Comment: Can you not use `text-overflow: ellipsis` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: `:not()` is a pseudo-*class*, not a pseudo-element.

Comment: Ok well I'm using both aren't I?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the ellipsis I will look into that thank you.

Comment: What is `font-family` utilized ? `width` , `height` requirement of `first-line` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a height on the div and use CSS Overflow:

```
.text-body {
    height: 40px; // or whatever height
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle of what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/momg7y3j/)

Comment: I need the box to scale responsively alongside image posts so setting a height restricts this, doesn't it?

Comment: You could set a min or max height to help with the responsiveness. Do you always only show the first line? For responsiveness you may have to calculate the height using JS.

Comment: I think that might be more complicated, and text-overflow: ellipsis better suited but thank you anyway.